# How should I use opencv in an iOS ARC project?

Tags: objective-c, opencv, automatic-ref-counting

Can I use opencv in ARC project? For example, if I create a Mat *mat = new Mat(.....), should I release it manually by delete mat, or the compiler automatically release the object?

Comment: Just did some experiments, non Objective c Object need to be released by hand.